# Variation of gravity in tetrad (vierbein) formalism using xAct or other computer algebra for wolfram language

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, software

I recently did some calculations in teleparallel gravity, where the fundamental variables are tetrad and  flat spin connection.  The Lagrangian density of teleparallel gravity is given by
\begin{equation}\label{lagtele}
\mathcal{L}_{/\!/}\left(h,A\right)=\frac{h}{4 \kappa} T^a{}_{\mu \nu} S_a{}^{\mu \nu},
\end{equation}
where we use

- the frame field tensor $h$ with components  $h_\mu^a$,
- the connection $A$ with components $ A^a_{b \mu}$ (which is such that $R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}(A)=0$),
- the  determinant $h=\operatorname{det} h_\mu^a$,
- the torsion tensor $T^a{}_{\mu \nu}\left(h,A\right)=\partial_\mu h_\nu^a-\partial_\nu h_\mu^a+ A_{b \mu}^a h_\nu^b- A_{b \nu}^a h_\mu^b$,
- the vector torsion $T^\mu=T^{\nu\mu}{}_{\nu}$,
- the contorsion tensor $K^a{}_{b \mu}=\frac{1}{2}\left(T_\mu{}^a{}_b+T_b{}^a{}_\mu-T^a{}_{b\mu}\right)$, and
- the  superpotential  $S_a{}^{\mu \nu}=K^{\mu \nu}{}_a-h_a^\nu T^\mu+h_a^\mu T^\nu$.

I was wondering if xAct can calculate the functional derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to the tetrad $h^a_\nu$ and spin connection $A^a{}_{b\mu}$.  I have not used xAct before, but I know it works well in the metric formalism.  For example,

- `VarD[g[-a,-b],cd][L]` returns $\frac{\delta L}{\delta g_{a b}}$ while integrating by parts with respect to the covariant derivative `cd`.
- `VarL[g[-a,-b],cd][L]` returns $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta(\sqrt{-g} L)}{\delta g_{a b}}$  while integrating by parts with respect to the covariant derivative `cd`.

Besides the action variation, I need to calculate some other variation which I may need to use in the future — for example, the superpotential variation $\frac{\delta S_a{}^{\rho\sigma}}{\delta A^{b}{}_{c\mu}} \delta A^b{}_{c\mu} $ and $\frac{\delta S_a{}^{\rho\sigma}}{\delta h^{b}{}_{\mu}} \delta h^b{}_{\mu} $. I am currently calculating these things by hand. I wonder if there is a package that can figure these things out; I'd be happy to learn it.

Comment: Might [mathematica.se] be better suited for questions on the usage of xAct/Mathematica?